# VBA filtering data - combobox refresh

Tags: vba, combobox, filtering, autofilter

I have been trying for a long time but it seems i can't find the solution. To explain the process, in the userform (ComboBox_Shelf), the user chooses a certain entry, and that entry is the input for auto filtering a large data in another sheet. the output of filtering then is displayed in another combobox in the same window (ComboBox_Bricks). The problem is, the filtering does not work properly when different entries are chosen. for instance, in the screenshot, Max Muster is chosen as entry, however, the bricks display should only show "Gold" after filtering, however, somehow, it filters two entries instead of the chosen one.

The following line of code ------PCPcockpit.ComboBox_Bricks.RowSource = APISheet & "!" & Sheets(APISheet).Range("A2", Sheets(APISheet).Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Address----- is called every time when the user checks out the bricks list after filtering. Thus, it should normally display the list filtered out.

[image: demonstration]

```
Sub Filterindata()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(APISheet).AutoFilterMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("API").Range("A1:CH22").AutoFilter Field:=86, 
Criteria1:=PCPcockpit.ComboBox_Shelf.value

Call Globalvariables
PCPcockpit.ComboBox_Bricks.RowSource = APISheet & "!" & Sheets(APISheet).Range("A2", Sheets(APISheet).Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Address
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess the problem with filtering is that, it does not delete the non-criteria input, it only hides them. So, if the input entry corresponds to a row 7, then list will display all entries from row 1 to 7. Any solution to this?

Comment: Before loading it into the ComboBox, search the range and save the visible rows to a seperate range variable. Then put that range as the RowSource.